Why does the forecast for some series degrade when using a VARMA model comparing to independent ARMA models?
I am working with multiple time series that I suspect are correlated, and I have assumed that using a VARMA model would at least not degrade the forecasts of each series, if not improve them. However, when I use statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax in Python to predict two time series, the forecast for one of them degrades compared to using univariate models.
I have ensured that the series are stationary. What could be the reasons for the degraded forecast performance for one of the series when using a VARMA model? Is this due to computational constraints in solving the VARMA models, or is there a theoretical aspect of VARMA models that I might be missing?
